# How open subpanel quickcreate form without top_buttons array

Tags: sugarcrm

Sugar CRM 6.5

Need to open subpanel quickcreate form from custom bottons in the list_fields (not from top_buttons), something like this:

```
...    
'list_fields' => 
 array (   
'quick_create' => 
    array (
      'vname' => 'LBL_QUICK_CREATE',
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopCreateButton',
      'width' => '3%',
    ),
...
```